# Unsure how to approach multithreading a complex function in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am confused about how to multi-thread a Python 2.7 application.

I included a simplified version of the code below. In essence a list of items is iterated and a function is called. The function "edit_file" is not cpu or hard drive intense, does not return a value and edits an independent file. That is, no two functions ever edit the same file.

As such this application can use multiple threads.

The complexity is that a different set of parameters must be used depending on what the item is. Also the set of parameters changes and is itself an output from another function.

```
items = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', ... , 'zulu']

for item in items:
    if func(item) == 'a':
        edit_file(item, parameter_set1)
    else func(item) == 'b':
        function(item, parameter_set2)
        if another_variable > 0:
            edit_file(item, parameter_set3)
```

How to multithread such an application?

Comment: Note that multithreading im Python isn't usually actually multiple threads over CPU cores, they will still utelize one core (thread) in the CPU. The only thing you'll gain here is "paralell code execution" on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `edit_file` is IO bound because of its name, so it makes it a candidate for Python multithreading. CPU bound computation would not be, because Python uses a Global Interpreter Lock that only allows one thread at a time to be active in a Python process - but another thread can run while one is blocked in IO.

You could use a pool of worker threads here:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadedPool

def process(item):
    if func(item) == 'a':
        edit_file(item, parameter_set1)
    else func(item) == 'b':
        function(item, parameter_set2)
        if another_variable > 0:
            edit_file(item, parameter_set3)

nThreads = 8  # number of concurrent threads
pool = ThreadedPool(nThreads)

pool.map(process, items)
pool.close()
```

(I kept you code unchanged in process, even if I think that `function` should be `edit_file`...)